# Eclipse debug “unable to install breakpoint in“

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Although I have tagged this with java it is not explicitly a java issue.
I am upgrading a Vaadin application from Vaadin 8 to Vaadin 23.
my set up is
OS windows 10
Eclipse Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0) Build id: 20220310-1457
apache tomcat 9.0.60
apache maven 3.8.5
Java adopt open jdk-11.0.10.9

I am unable to run any application as a Tomcat server or a Maven build and debug it in eclipse.
I am able to debug when it is a pure java application.
I was initially able to build and debug the Vaadin 8 application with a Tomcat server or a Maven build.

However after I started the upgrade to Vaadin 23  Eclipse "broke" and I cannot fix it. I keep getting
“unable to install breakpoint in “ when debugging with Tomcat server or Maven. And even if I just continue Eclipse ignores the break points.(NB I dont get this when I run it as a java application)

I have tried to make a new Spring Vaadin application at https://spring.io/quickstart and I am getting the same issue.
So new work space and project does not fix the issue.
I have also deleted and rebuild the .m2 and .eclipse folders.

I have unset and applied and reset and applied
Window => Preferences => Java =>Compiler (class file generation)

- Add variable attributes...
- Add line number attributes...
- Add source file name...

I have unset and applied and reset and applied
Window => Preferences => Maven

- Debug Output

I have checked that the
Window => Preferences => Maven => installations

- points to my maven 3.8.5  installation

Window => Run/Debug

- Launch in debug mode when workspace contains break points (.) ALWAYS

Window => Server => Runtime Environment

- points to the apache tomcat 9.0.60 installation

The following environment vars are also set and point to the relevant installation

- JAVA_HOME
- M2_HOME
- MAVEN_HOME

I have checked and gone through:

[Eclipse - Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes)

[Eclipse Unable to install breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760856/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint)

I don't want to un-install  an re- install every thing.
What have I missed?

---

Edit

Steps to reproduce
go to
https://start.spring.io/
select

- Mavan project
- Language Java
- Spring boot 2.6.8
- Packaging War
- Java 11

In dependencies add

- Vaadin
- Spring boot Dev tools
- Liquibase Migration

Select generate and download

- Demo.zip

Import into eclipse

In eclipse Select Windows => View

- Create new server
- Point to Tomcat 9 installation
- VM arguments are.

  -Dcatalina.base="C:\work\programming\spring.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="C:\work\projects\common_libraries\apache-tomcat-9.0.60" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\work\programming\spring.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED

Create debug line break point in DemoApplication.java on line with
SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

Start server :
Get error message “unable to install breakpoint in...“

(NB If I debug this as a java application it stops at the breakpoint)

Comment: Using breakpoints requires that the code has been compiled with debug information and that the source has been correctly attached. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am sure it must be an eclipse / tomcat / maven issue.
I have updated the question above. I hope it helps clarify. I cannot see how to add the demo.zip to the question.
I get this issue on my machine you will in all probability not get the same issue on yours.

Comment: Prove it by a minimal reproducible example. If it is not reproducible, it can't be an Eclipse, Tomcat or Maven issue. You can use GitHub, etc. to share your minimal example project.

Comment: This is about as minimal as I can get. https://github.com/22ka/demo Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: You have the same problem in there? In which file and line number?

Comment: In DemoApplication.java on line (13) the line with with SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
but that line is correct it just Eclipse or Tomcat or Maven that is not working

Comment: When running your application as a web application in Tomcat, I would guess (without being a web developer) the main method will never be called.